# Redshift Regex count. Repetition operator error

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to do a simple regex pattern match in Redshift

I have this code and I get the following error:

```
REGEXP_COUNT ( "code", '^(?=.{8}$)[A-z]{2,5}[0-9]{3,6}$' )
```

```
ERROR: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression fragment: '^(?>>>HERE>>>=.{8}$)[A-'.
```

The pattern works fine in testing in python and online checkers I'm guessing its a REGEX language problem. I have checked in PostgreSQL documentation on REGEX to try get help as I can't find much details on actual Redshift.

Thanks,

Comment: The [redshift regex documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html) indicates that it doesn't support any type of lookaround

Comment: Ahh thank you didnt look hard enough obviously..